# Can't save changes on INSERTed records

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have Entity Framework application that has a model generated from Database (Database First approach).

My function adds new records to the `DbSet`. After I add them all I'm trying to save changes to the table in the Database through `db.SaveChanges()`. The same function is used for all tables in the Database. They all have the same format:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Column1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Column2] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Column3] [decimal](20, 10) NULL,
    [cs_Table1]  AS (checksum([Column1],[Column2])),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Some tables have more or less columns. The problem is that importing new records works for most of the tables but for two it doesn't. I've checked many times. They don't differ in any significant way. When I try to save changes on those two tables I get no errors it executes. I've debugged it, it correctly passes new instances but on `db.SaveChanges()` it doesn't do anything.

I've read in other posts that sometimes you have some kind of copy of the Database and it copies there. How can I check this? And why it works on some of the tables and on some doesn't. It's the same Database.

Snippet where I save the changes:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(excel, FileMode.Open))
{
    My_Model db = new My_Model ();
    var class = new ExcelExtractingClass(db);
    class.ImportFromExcel(stream);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

`ImportFromExcel` is a long function. But I'm sure it works. All it does in regards to my problem is using: `DbSet.Add(entity)`. But it works for most of the tables. DbSet is defined in `My_Model` it was generated from Database.

Comment: Where is your C# code for Add/Update.

Comment: It's basic `Add` method, no updates. `db.DbSet.Add(record)` There is no problem with function since it works on all tables. I get no errors. It's just isn't saved for those two tables in the Database.

Comment: Before Save you have to Add your entity like below : dbset.Add(entity); dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added; dataContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: `db` is made of `IDbSets` and it has no `Entry()` method. And how would it explain that it works on  most cases without this method?

Comment: Please share your C# code where you are trying to do saveChanges().

Comment: I've added the use of `SaveChanges()` to the post.

Comment: Without seeing the code I doubt anyone can tell you what might be missing/wrong. You need to step through it, see where it is creating the entities, and adding them to the DbSet. The code either isn't adding entities to the DbSet where you expect it would, or there is exception handling that is swallowing the evidence for a problem.

Comment: I was sure the code was working because why wouldn't it. It got me 10/12 tables to database. But indeed after debuging whole code and nitpicking I've found a logic that made skip Adding new records. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a thorough debugging I've found that my logic which skipped `Adding` new records was not working properly for those two tables.